# What is wrong with my transpose function?

Tags: c++, arrays

I am trying to transpose a matrix, like below. I am passing the array by reference, and somehow it is not working (AFTER is same as BEFORE). I am not sure why.

But, What I am really surprised about is that the array is not transposed even inside the `transpose()` function (how can INSIDE be the same as BEFORE??). What am I missing?

```
#include <iostream>

template <int M, int N>
void print1(int (&src)[M][N]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++)
            printf("%2d\t", src[i][j]);
        std::cout << std::endl;
    }
}

template <int M, int N>
void transpose(int (&src)[M][N]) {
    for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
        for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
            if (i == j) continue;
            int temp = src[i][j];
            src[i][j] = src[j][i];
            src[j][i] = temp;
        }
    }
    std::cout << "\nINSIDE:\n";
    print1(src);
}

int main() {

    int src[][4] = {
        { 1,  2,  3,  4},
        { 5,  6,  7,  8},
        { 9, 10, 11, 12},
        {13, 14, 15, 16},
    };

    std::cout << "BEFORE:\n";
    print1(src);
    transpose(src);

    std::cout << "\nAFTER:\n";
    print1(src);
}
```

Output:

```
$ ./a.out
BEFORE:
 1       2       3       4
 5       6       7       8
 9      10      11      12
13      14      15      16

INSIDE:
 1       2       3       4
 5       6       7       8
 9      10      11      12
13      14      15      16

AFTER:
 1       2       3       4
 5       6       7       8
 9      10      11      12
13      14      15      16
$
```

Comment: `src[1][2]` gets swapped with `src[2][1]`, and later `src[2][1]` gets swapped back with `src[1][2]`. Change the loop condition to skip the swap when `i <= j` instead of when `i == j`.

Comment: Also, you can use `std::swap(src[i][j], src[j][i]);` to exchange the values without having to declare a temporary variable.

Comment: You modified your question? Someone coming in to read this after 1 year will never know what you did there! Plus transpose is defined only for square matrix so use only single template parameter.

Comment: No, I dint modify. Why do you think I did?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Are you maybe transposing it twice:

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < N; j++) {
        if (i == j) continue;
        int temp = src[i][j];
        src[i][j] = src[j][i];
        src[j][i] = temp;
    }
}
```

i.e. substitute `src(i,j)` for `src(j,i)`... and then substitute `src(j,i)` for `src(i,j)`?

Answer (score 0):

A better optimization is

```
for(int i = 0; i < M; i++) {
    for(int j = 0; j < i; j++) { <----------------  Compare j with i and not with N
        // if (i == j) continue;    <----------------  No need to do this extra check
        int temp = src[i][j];
        src[i][j] = src[j][i];
        src[j][i] = temp;
    }
}
```